# In Dax, when creating a measure, how do I create a variable that summarises another summarised table variable? Analysing Price Bins for Ecommerce

Tags: powerbi, dax

Disclaimer: Novice, and I apologise if I completely misunderstand main concepts in DAX.

Context: Ecommerce company, understand effects on sales, revenue, profit from price of product. In order to optimise pricing.

Overall Objective: To analyse list prices for our products over time, to evaluate the most efficient price points.

Aim here: To group prices into bins of 2.5. Then to output the price bin that yields the highest quantity sold per day.

Source Data `[sku_pricing]`:

| Main_Date | Channel | Territory | SKU | List_Price | Line_qty | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | Amazon | UK | SKU-1 | 39.99 | 4 | 159.96 |
| 2022-01-01 | Website | UK | SKU-1 | 44.99 | 2 | 99.98 |
| 2022-01-02 | Website | US | SKU-2 | 39.99 | 1 | 39.99 |
| 2022-01-02 | Website | EU | SKU-2 | 28.99 | 1 | 28.99 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

After several hours, I have a successful measure that outputs the Average Quantity Sold Per Day by Price Bin.

DAX:

```
qty_sold_per_day_per_price_bin = 
VAR PriceBins =
    DISTINCT(Price_bins[price_bin])
VAR grouped =
    SUMMARIZE(
        sku_pricing,
        sku_pricing[Main_Date],
                "Price Bin", MAXX(
            FILTER(
                Price_bins,
                [Price_bin] <= [list_price_weighted] &&
                [Price_bin] + 2.5 > [list_price_weighted]
            ),
            [Price_bin]
        ),
        "Qty", SUM(sku_pricing[line_qty])
    )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX(
        FILTER(
            grouped,
            [Price Bin] >= MINX(PriceBins, [price_bin]) &&
            [Price Bin] < MAXX(PriceBins, [price_bin]) + 2.5
        ),
        [Qty]
    )
```

It outputs correctly to the below image.

[Average Quantity Sold Per Day by Price Bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pfcf.png)

However now I want to create a measure that 'simply' output the price bin that has the highest quantity sold per day. In the case of the example, £25.

This is my attempt, but apparently it fails due a variable not being able to aggregate a column of another summarised variable:

```
best_price_bin = 
VAR PriceBins =
    DISTINCT(Price_bins[price_bin])
VAR grouped =
    SUMMARIZE(
        sku_pricing,
        sku_pricing[Main_Date],
        "Price Bin", MAXX(
            FILTER(
                Price_bins,
                [Price_bin] <= [list_price_weighted] &&
                [Price_bin] + 2.5 > [list_price_weighted]
            ),
            [Price_bin]
        ),
        "Qty", SUM(sku_pricing[line_qty])
    )
VAR avg_qty_by_price_bin =
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(
            grouped,
            [Price Bin] >= MINX(PriceBins, [price_bin]) &&
            [Price Bin] < MAXX(PriceBins, [price_bin]) + 2.5
        ),
        "Price Bin", [Price Bin] // Error here
        "Avg Qty", AVERAGE(grouped[Qty] //Error here
    )
RETURN
    MAXX(
        TOPN(
            1, 
            avg_qty_by_price_bin, 
            [Avg Qty], 
            DESC
        ), 
        [Price Bin]
    )
```

Edit, more info:

`[Price Bin]` table is a table of numbers in intervals of 2.5, from between 2.5 and 250. E.g. 2.5, 5, 7. This is used to group list_prices into price bins. It is not joined to any table.

`[list_price_weighted]` is a weighted average. It could be replaced with `average(sku_pricing[list_price])` for the purposes of this example.

Please help on this, I've been working on it for hours.

Comment: Your formulas reference the following tables/columns/measures, none of which you have shared: `Price_bins[price_bin]`, `sku_pricing[Main_Date]`, `[list_price_weighted]`.

Comment: My mistake. Main_Date is the correct name for the Date column I used in the source data, it was a typo.

Regarding Price Bins, it is a table of numbers between 2.5 to 250, iterating in intervals of 2.5. E.g. 2.5, 5, 7.5. This is used to group the prices into these price bins.

The list_price_weighted is 

`SUMX(sku_pricing,sku_pricing[list_price]*sku_pricing[line_qty])/sum(sku_pricing[line_qty])`

But could be replaced by average(list_price) for the purposes of this example.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The issue was using Summarize to aggregate a variable within a summarized table.

The solution was to use Groupby() in the variable that referenced the Summarized variable.

Further reading: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/nested-grouping-using-groupby-vs-summarize/

Final measure:

```
    best_price_bin = 
VAR PriceBins =
    DISTINCT(Price_bins[price_bin])
VAR grouped =
    SUMMARIZE(
        sku_pricing,
        sku_pricing[Main_Date],
        "Price Bin", MAXX(
            FILTER(
                Price_bins,
                [Price_bin] <= [list_price_weighted] &&
                [Price_bin] + 2.5 > [list_price_weighted]
            ),
            [Price_bin]
        ),
        "Qty", SUM(sku_pricing[line_qty])
    )
VAR avg_qty_by_price_bin =
    groupby(
        grouped,
        [Price Bin],
        "Avg Qty", averagex(currentgroup(), [Qty])
    )


RETURN
    MAXX(
        TOPN(
            1, 
            avg_qty_by_price_bin, 
            [Avg Qty], 
            DESC
        ), 
        [Price Bin]
    )
```